# Simple mysql function help: how to store a function, use it to manipulate data and write data to new table

Tags: mysql, function, call

I am new to MySQL and need some help with functions in MySQL.  Say I have some data stored in MySQL that I want to bring into a function, do some stuff and then output the result to another table.

Say that table 'data' has columns x and y. I want my function to grab a pair of x,y and if x or y is not equal 0 then add x and y together and store in another table called result?

I get how to store the function where I have done:

```
DELIMITER $$    
CREATE FUNCTION adder(x,y)
  IF x = 0 OR y=0 THEN
      RETURN 0;
  END IF;
  RETURN x+y; END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I don't know how to use this in my MySQL statements and write the result to a new table.  Ideally this will look at all the rows of table data and write the result to the new table. All help is GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query

```
INSERT INTO Result SELECT adder(x, y) from Data;
```

Where `Result` is the name of the table in which you want to enter the data.
And `Data` is the table whose columns you want to add.

Here is the fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0a2d/1